# Changing results of a random process

Tags: probability, statistics

A very sexist population prefers boys to girls.  All parents try various strategies (but not neglect, abuse, or selective abortion) to increase the number of boys, such as giving birth repeatedly until they get one son.  Is it true that no strategy can change the society's male:female ratio?  If so, prove it; if not, give a counterexample.

My cousin and I started discussing this question recently.  I thought it was intuitively obvious that no strategy could work, while he thought it was obvious that some strategies do work.  Neither of us could conclusively prove our position.

Comment: Concentrate on births, not "families" to validate your intuition.

Comment: The usual approach to this assumes that each child born to each woman has exactly the same prior probability to be a boy as a child born to any other women. If instead some women have higher prior probabilities to give birth to boys and others have lower prior probabilities to do so, then there are strategies that can change the male:female ratio. Consider the strategy in your first paragraph, for example; see what effect it has when the prior probabilities are unequal. (Ironic, isn't it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can show that no matter what strategy a family takes, their expected no. of boys and girls respectively must be equal.

Let $B_n$ and $G_n$ be the no. of boys and girls respectively after $n$ births in a family. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time, i.e. some decision rule for stopping making kids (this will include all strategies which are based on information up to each birth, i.e. you cannot predict what the next child will be). For example the strategy you gave is a stopping time.

Let $X_n = B_n-G_n$. Now we want to show that for any stopping time $\tau$, $E[X_\tau]=0$.

Note that we have $E[|X_{n+1}-X_n| \mid \mathcal F_n]=1$ and assume that $E[\tau]<\infty$. With these conditions, by Optional Stopping Theorem we have
$$
E[X_\tau]=0
$$
as we wanted. So they cannot on average alter the ratio of boys vs girls.

Note however that we need the condition $E[\tau]<\infty$ to use Optional Stopping Theorem. I.e. the expected no. of births before they stop must be finite. This is obviously true in the real world since people have finite lives and it is certainly true for the strategy you gave since $E[\tau]=2<\infty$. So you are right given that we are in the real world, otherwise it will hold in general whenever $E[\tau]<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the expected value of the **geometric distribution**.

If the probability of getting a boy is 0.5, then the expected value will be 2. On average parents need 2 trials to get a boy. This means the parents, on average, have already one daughter till they stop. Thus the strategy doesn´t help, if $p=0.5$.